# Change MediaWiki category page title with {{DISPLAYTITLE:xyz}} and use [[Category:xyz]]

Tags: mediawiki

If you create a category page "xyz" and then use {{DISPLAYTITLE:abc}}, the category page will be displayed as "abc". Using [[Category:abc]] will result in a red link as a category "abc" does not exist.

Is it possible to make [[Category:abc]] work, i.e. to link to the category "xyz". Thank you.

Comment: No this is not possible.

Comment: You could try creating a redirect? But I'm not sure if pages assigned to the redirected category would appear in the target category

Comment: Just create page `Category:abc` with the content `#REDIRECT [[Category:xyz]]`.

Comment: Thanks, a category:abc with the redirect works. But the use of [[category:abc]] in a page "asd" brings the page into this category, but not into category:xyz. Clicking on the category:abc on the page "asd" then takes you to the empty category:xyz.

Comment: Ok, it is possible with a double categorization. The category:abc with the content #REDIRECT [[Category:xyz]] is hidden with __HIDDENCAT__. Then both categories can be used in one page, but only the category:abc is displayed. Remains how to hide the Hidden category.